# MacBook Air 2017 not booting after Big Sur upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a MacBook Air 13" mid 2017 from 2 years ago. Until two days ago it was running smooth. Things got worse after trying to update to Big Sur from the latest release of Catalina.

**Problem:** The BigSur update started just fine, MBA rebooted and the apple logo with the progress bar displayed showing the remaining time. At around 50% the MBA rebooted itself (battery at 100%, attached to the power supply and no user input). From this moment the MBA is stuck in an endless boot loop: apple logo appears, loads to 100%, instantly shuts down and the cycle repeats.

**What I have tried so far:**

- I've tryed both **NVRAM** and **SMC** reset
- **reinstalling** the OS from online recovery and from a Catalina bootable USB.
- **replace** the **SSD** with a working one (tested in another MBA)

---

I have found a *solution* but it's more of an hack and totally defeats the purpouse of having a notebook. If I detatch the battery from the logic board and and reattach it, the first boot works perfectly: notebook starts, works like a charm. But if I shutdown the OS and try to start again the MBA seams dead. The fan starts spinning for about five seconds with black display and no chime and then it stops and continues to do this loop of starting and stopping, unless I detach the battery again. In this state every command (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>; <kbd>⇪</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>) doesn't even work.

- What can I do to fix this problem?
- Am I doomed to replace the logic
  board?

Comment: Have you done the hardware test by hitting `D` while boot? Do you have a backup that you could restore? Have you tried reinstalling an *older* version than BigSur? Just as info: When the battery is detached the MBA will heavily throttle its performance, so *maybe* there is some power consumption/overheating issue at play...

Comment: After rereading your question I realized that you most likely already tried installing Catalina. Can you boot from an external hard drive? Also, have you tried all the startup modes? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255. I don't know what `shift` + `alt` + `ctrl`+ `power` does tbh.